# What is (if there is) the generic term for equalities and inequalities

Tags: inequality, terminology, linear-programming

I'm writing a text about a particular [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) (LP)I optimization problem, that is described using a mixture of inequalities (`≤`, `≥`) and equalities (`=`). My question now is: is there an generic term for these two concepts? Asking Google only yielded [a message on `sci.logic` from 2012](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sci.logic/y9GRUA9kXUI/U9ckOiGMaSMJ) without a helpful answer. Wikipedia surfing suggested "binary relation", but that is far *too* generic.

If the answer is "no" and there is a reason for that (e.g. because I am doing a mathematical fruit salad comparison), I would also accept that as an answer.

**Edit** clarifying why I am not simply relying on the fact that every LP can be transformed into canonical form ($\max\, \mathbf{c}^\textsf{T}\mathbf{x}\ \, s.t. \mathbf{Ax \leq b}, \mathbf{x \geq 0}$), und thus simply use the word *inequality* exclusively: in the text I am refering to a model written in a software environment similar to [AMPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMPL), which hides this transformation into canonical form and allows the user to use both equalities and inequalities in the problem definition.

Comment: Something to do with **ordering?**  Say like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order

Comment: I guess you can rearrange everything (or multiply by $-1$ if preferred) to get the inequalities for the same direction. Also, an equation can be replaced to two inequalities. So, isn't simply *inequality* is what you are looking for?

Comment: Berci: see my edit that clarifies why *inequality* is not what I was looking for.

Comment: Well, after the edit, I would still calmly use the term '*inequality*' (or '*relation*') for the generic name of possible input. Just introduce that you will use this word 'relation' in this sense.

Comment: Relations and conditions are good alternatives.

Comment: Berci, Lucian: If one of you converts their comments into an answer, I would be inclined to accept, even though it is not the answer I hoped for :)

Comment: Macavity: Interesting direction; I just do not know how to map "order" to a term that becomes a lose synonym for `{equality, inequality}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of no term to describe equalities and inequalities together without relying on some context.

In the context of linear programming, **constraints** probably captures both aspects nicely. But in more general optimization, other things could be considered constraints as well, like for example the constraint that a given variable must be an integer, which can't be expressed using (in)equalities.

In many branches of mathematics you can expect speakers to refer to them as **relations** or **conditions** if the context makes the meaning clear enough. That could either be because the speaker established the term up front, or because the audience has been staring at equalities and inequalities for several minutes so they know what they are talking about. In written texts, a clear definition is of course preferable. If you provide a local definition, you might as well define the term **inequality** itself to *also* include equalities. Some readers will get confused by this, but others will be grateful because the term is closer to their way of thinking.

The term “binary relations” would feel strange for both the spoken and the written use case, since it's too specific to be considered a simple abbreviation. It makes people think you're either talking about *all* binary relations, or you're for some reason emphasizing the fact that the relations are binary not ternary or whatever.

*This answer includes input from several comments, so I'm making this community wiki.*